# Spark dataset to_date/year function

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract date from a timestamp column of an object in dataset filter. I want to find all people who made a logged in entry on 2010

```
class Person{
String name;
Timestamp loggedat;
}
List<Person> persons;
Dataset<Person> ds = spark.createDataset(
                persons,
                Encoders.bean(Person.class)
            );
ds.select(to_date(ds.col("loggedat"),"y")==2010);
```

This select does not seem to work. Please help on how to extract year from Timestamp and filter out data.

Comment: To the get the year part , you should pass `"yyyy"` . and since you are comparing it with 2010 , i guess you need to do it in filter condition and not select . reference for to_date function  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_date(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Comment: If you want to extract year , can you use the year function ? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#year(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Comment: @RajatMishra - adding "yyyy" is not working. It says methos to_Date is undefined

Comment: @RajatMishra It worked , I forgot to import import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Answer (score 1):

To the get the year part , you should pass `"yyyy"` with `to_date` function.

Reference : [Spark-SQL Api doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_date(org.apache.spark.sql.Column))